# Is it possible to make iOS Safari upload original HEIC photos without JPEG conversion?

Tags: html, file-upload, mobile-safari

iOS stores the pictures taken with the camera in HEIC. These files are twice as small as a JPEG of equivalent quality. I could find a way deal with them on my back end (for one, libvips seems to support HEIC), thus saving data for the user. The problem: as of iOS 13, Safari insists on converting HEIC to JPEG on upload and thus doubling the file size.

This:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/heic" name="file"/>
```

doesn't do the trick either. Neither does `image/heif`.

Am I missing something, or is it flat out impossible and I have to make do with data-wasting jpegs?

Comment: Interested in the solution myself

Comment: I'm looking to do this too. They really should have made the accept mime type opt in for the old behavior, which was just preserving HEIC (which admittedly did cause a lot of headaches when HEIC first came out). The only workaround I have right now is making the user Save to Files" and then upload from Files rather than photos, which seems to preserve the HEIC.

Comment: Looking all around the web for a solution and 2 years later none. Apple has to intervene, let us have a descriptor on our form on how to handle that upload without conversion please…

Comment: I think it converts the file to jpeg when you select it, before the upload starts.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this answer can be of any help since it is so convoluted but it looks like if you upload your picture as a file, it should stay .heic
This is absolutely not practical tho, as you have to save any photo you want to upload into your files first (app "Files")...

I did it recently during a trip with friends to pool photos from several iPhones on my NAS but it was a hassle to get everyone to do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34115504)